# C# rename a file to the same name as a file from a different directory

Tags: c#

For example I have 2 directories with both the same file, and when I renamed the file in the 1st directory, it should be renamed in the 2nd directory as well. If the file is renamed in the 2nd directory, I dont want it to be renamed in the first. So just one way. Now people use `File.Move` for renaming in the same directory, but that wont work for me, since I dont want the file to be gone from the first directory. So I figured I should use `Copy` , but the problem is, if it copies the 2nd directory has 2 files. 1 with the old name (since it already existed) + the copy of the file in the first directory. So I figured I have to delete the old file in the second directory, but for some reason this wont work for me. It wont delete the old file.

Here is my code:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    String source = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Directory1"]; // defined this in the app config
    String target = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"Directory2"];
    filepath = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
    veryoldname = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

    File.Delete(Path.Combine(target, veryoldname));
    File.Copy(filepath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name)); 
}
```

I was wondering 3 things here.

1. Is this the best way to rename a file according to a file in a different directory?
2. If not, how should I do it?
3. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not use `File.Move`? Get new filename from source directory, use `File.Move` on target to the new name.

Comment: @Tobberoth so File.Move(filepath,target) in my case? I get the error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: Why are you moving the source file to the target? Wasn't the point to rename a target file to the same name as a source file which has changed name? You're supposed to move the target file to the target folder, but with the new name.

Comment: @tobberoth yeah okay but how do I even implement this in the File.Move? It needs the Path of dir 3, the old name and the new name which he gets from the first dir. How do you even fit this in the file.move?

Comment: What about `File.Move(Path.Combine(target,veryoldname), Path.Combine(target,e.Name)`? This takes the file with the old name and simply renames it to `e.Name`.

Comment: @Tobberoth It gives me: target, e.name(/2/lol.txt) does not exist. which is weird. Since It shouldn't exist but it should be made there.

Comment: You should probably look at how you're handling your directories, `/2/lol.txt` doesn't look like a correct path, or are you running this on linux using Mono?

Comment: @Tobberoth no it's like something like: C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\Loko\3

Comment: Do you mean that e.Name is `/2/lol.txt` then? I don't get it. As long as target is a proper path and veryoldname/e.Name are proper filenames, it's impossible to get a "does not exist" error unless the file with the old name has been deleted or renamed previously.

Comment: @Tobberoth Target is a proper path(C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\Loko\3), e.Name is the name which it changes to, in my case(lol.txt). veryoldname is described in the question and source = C:\Users\Loko\Desktop\Loko\1

Comment: Oh. Well there's your problem, veryoldname is not the old name, it's the new name. It's built from the source path and e.Name, which is the new file. You need the file in target you want to rename, the name it had before the change.

Comment: @Tobberoth It was. Before I saw your comment, I noticed it as well. Answer so I can accept it :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the comment discussion rolled into an answer:

Change:

```
veryoldname = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
```

To:

```
veryoldname = e.OldName;
```

And change:

```
File.Delete(Path.Combine(target, veryoldname));
File.Copy(filepath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
```

To:

```
File.Move(Path.Combine(target,veryoldname),Path.Combine(target,e.Name));
```